# Moving text position on a nav bar

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, position

UPDATE: Okay I changed the margin on #access ul although now when I hover over it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z2BF.jpg

Also is it possible to change the spacing between the page titles (sorry still learning css!)

I'm currently designing my wordpress theme and wondering how I could move the text up a bit to center up with the nav bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3BOH.png

I'm using custom font as well. Here is my css:

```
#access {
background: #252525;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 40px;
}
#access ul {
list-style: none;
margin: -8px -13px -10px -13px;
padding-left: 0;
color:#000;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(14,14,14,0.8);
text-transform:uppercase;
font: 24px Giantypo, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#access li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#access a {
display: block;
line-height: 2.5em;
padding: 0 1em;
text-decoration: none;
color:#f3f3f3;
}
#access ul ul {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
display: none;
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul ul {
left: 100%;
top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
background: #3e5d8c;
line-height: 1em;
padding: .5em .5em .5em 1em;
width: 10em;
height: auto;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
background: #3e5d8c;
}
#access ul ul a:hover {
background: #3e5d8c;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
}
```

Any help would be great!

Cheers,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top margin of unordered list must be negatie value. For example:

```
margin: -7px 0 0 0;
```

Comment: Okay I changed the margin on #access ul although now when I hover over it looks like this: http://imgur.com/NeUzN

Comment: On #access a remove line-height or paddings.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `line-height` to be equal to its `height`. On `#access a`, I believe, but I cannot know for sure without seeing the HTML. And I cannot know its height without seeing all of it live.

Comment: Okay I changed the margin on #access ul although now when I hover over it looks like this: http://imgur.com/NeUzN

Comment: I'll put it up on my site to let you have a look at it.